# Trying to access a method with method calls throws multiple error

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods

I am trying to access a method from a switch menu to display data that's stored in a vector. However, I'm not sure how to tell case 1 to go the the method that takes in the method call. 
The error list is below:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'applicant' : undeclared identifier    
Error   2   error C2275: 'Applicant' : illegal use of this type as an expression    
Error   3   error C3861: 'viewApp': identifier not found
```

Below is problematic the code I'm currently working on.

```
 do
    {
    std::cout << "Menu\n";
    std::cout << "\t1. View Applications\n";
    std::cout << "\t2. Record Orders\n";
    std::cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> option;

  switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                viewApp(Applicant& applicant);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                Order cO;
                cO.createOrder();
            }
        default: 
            std:cout << option << " is not a valid menu item.\n";
            std::cout << endl;
}
}
while(option !=5);
```

This is currently a snippet of the switch menu and I need 'case 1' to go to the viewApp()  method below.

```
int viewApp(Applicant& applicant) //can't get the switch to go to this method
{
//code
}

void Order::createOrder() //this works fine and the switch menu goes straight to it
{
//code
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, many thanks.
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method call:

```
viewApp(Applicant& applicant);
```

You're renaming the type of the argument, which isn't necessary (or allowed within the grammar of the language).

```
viewApp(applicant);
```

Would work if applicant was in scope, but before that you'll need to create it:

```
Applicant applicant;
viewApp(applicant);
```

Also, you might have a bug in the menu selection code as written. The second case statement needs a break so it doesn't automatically fall through to the default case and always trigger the "menu option not found" bit.

Comment: Thanks, for the clear answer. However, now I have two errors, c3861 'viewApp' Identifier not found and c2530 'applicant' references must be initialized.  Not sure how to fix, thanks.

Comment: Where is viewApp defined? Have you included the header that declares it into the current file? Also, what constructors are available for applicant? I assumed the empty constructor was available because of how you were trying to use it.

Comment: Okay I've managed to solve the c3861 error, but still getting c2530 error, and yes empty constructor available for applicant.

Comment: `References must be initialized`: That's because `Applicant &applicant` is a reference. Either initialize it or drop the reference identifier (`&`).

Comment: @TomCummins `3861 'viewApp' Identifier not found` is because you haven't declared `viewApp` before you use it. Either move the definition before the use (probably before `main`) or add a prototype declaration before the use.

Comment: @AdamS Thanks for the help. However, I'm not sure how to initialize the reference applicant?

Comment: @TomCummins With another copy of an `Applicant` object for example. The `&` makes `applicant` to a reference. But just change it to `Applicant applicant;` as you don't want a reference here but you want an original object. The *reference* the function `viewApp` takes as an argument is a reference to that very instance.

Comment: @AdamS Of course it's easy as that and I should have known. Maybe I'm just giving up slowly :P